# EmberJS redirect() works strange

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have routes:

```
this.route('deals', function () {
    this.route('order', {path: ":id"});
});
```

In "deals" route I do this:

```
redirect(model, transition){
    if(transition.targetName != 'deals.order'){
      var order = model.orders.objectAt(0);

      return this.transitionTo('deals.order', order);
    }else{
      return this._super(model, transition);
    }
  },
```

It works fine if I open: `http://localhost:4200/deals/1`, but if then I go to any other route and then go to `/deals` with menu, it works such way:

```
Preparing to transition from 'deals.order' to ' settings.index' //any other route
Transitioned into 'settings.index' //here everything is ok still and next I click menu to go to "deals" route.

Preparing to transition from 'settings.index' to ' deals.index'
```

And next transitions go with no pouses and I absolutely have no idea why:

```
Transitioned into 'deals.order' (it goes with orders ID)
Preparing to transition from 'deals.order' to ' deals.index' //why???
Transitioned into 'deals.index' //why???
```

I even have no idea how to debug it!

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue on ember-twiddle.com or emberjs.jsbin.com?

Comment: it's really difficult, I have a complicated ember-cli based system with number of adapters.

Comment: I tried a similar setup and everything works as expected. Create a sample project with just the three routes, give hard coded data and check the output.

Comment: `redirect` hook doesn't gets called when you are transitioning from `deals.order` to `deals`

Comment: It's strange, I thought redirect is something permanently, so should I use didTransition hook?